# Passing a default value in Stored procedure

Tags: sql, if-statement, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I have a SP which writes the watermark value after each ADF pipeline run , below is the procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_write_Time_watermark] @LastModifiedtime datetime, @TableName varchar(50)
AS

BEGIN

UPDATE dbo.Store_Time_Watermarktable
SET [WatermarkValue] = @LastModifiedtime 
WHERE [TableName] = @TableName
END
```

I want to add a condition which says if the lastmodified value is null the set default value as 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 else take the new lastmodified time. How should i tweak the above procedure

Thanks

Comment: ...why is using `1900-01-01` preferable to `NULL`?

Comment: UPDATE dbo.Store_Time_Watermarktable
SET [WatermarkValue] = isnull(@LastModifiedtime ,'1900-01-01')
WHERE [TableName] = @TableName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `isnull` function, it returns the first non-null of two values.

```
SET WatermarkValue = isnull(@LastModifiedtime, '19000101')
```

If you had more than two values you would use `coalesce`

Comment: I did try is null and coalesce in my stored procedure and also tried to set default value as '1/1/1753 12:00:00' instead of '1900-01-01' but my ADF SP activity throws error as  '
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM' . This SP activity in ADF calls watermark SP and writes the recent watermark value in the watermark table